# I need to generate the following outputs

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate the following outputs using np array. i have attempted this and i am attaching the code to review.

Question 4: Consider the following array: (3 marks)

a)

```
z = np.array ([[[ 0, 1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6, 7], [ 8, 9, 10, 11]],  
     [[12, 13, 14,15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]
```

Produce these outputs:

```
     Array ([[ 4, 5, 9],  
     [14, 19, 22,23]])  

     Array ([[ 2, 16, 21],  
     [4,2, 18, 16]]
```

b)

```
u = np.array ([[ 0.58, 0.05, 0.84, 0.21],  
     [ 0.88, 0.98, 0.45, 0.13],  
     [ 0.1 , 0.52, 0.58, 0.38],  
     [ 0.84, 0.76, 0.25, 0.07]])
```

Replace the diagonal elements of u with (2, 11, 12, 31), and add 2 to all
values in x that are greater  than 0.38.

Comment: You have to provide Your efforts on solving this issue (Your code/What You have done/tried)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1):

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

array2 = np.array(
    [[0.58, 0.05, 0.84, 0.21], [0.88, 0.98, 0.45, 0.13], [0.1, 0.52, 0.58, 0.38], [0.84, 0.76, 0.25, 0.07]])

array2[0][0] = 2
array2[1][1] = 11
array2[2][2] = 12
array2[3][3] = 31
print(array2)
flatten = list(chain.from_iterable(array2))
for i in range(len(flatten)):
    if (flatten[i] > 2):
        flatten[i] = flatten[i] + 2

matrix = np.array(flatten).reshape(array2.shape)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: You are not supposed to provide an answer like this in this case. it is probably a homework question so he should provide his own efforts on this, not just be handed an answer, read here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)